# Spring Boot Application, All users share the same session in diffrenet browsers

Tags: maven, session, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working on a spring boot application, I tried to login from two browsers with different users, but when I refresh the page for the user1 I get the session of the user2 with the same instances.

Comment: Okay, that's kinda scary.  So, what was your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. You're going to have to provide a lot more detail in order for anyone to help you.

Comment: Define *two browsers*. Is that from firefox and chrome or is that multiple windows of the same browser?

Comment: Yes it's chrome and firefox, Is this may be because I did something wrong in the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: My question is what I should do to create a session for every user, isn't the spring Security Configuration enough?

Comment: If your session is shared between different browsers you are doing things really wrong. I doubt it is your security configuration but rather wrong usage of a singleton controller (in other words keeping state where you shouldn't).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because I didn't add the annotation @SessionScope in login and controller classes